# convert factor with 11 levels to character or numeric

Tags: r

I have the following data frame (imported from a csv) with a row of factors with 11 levels.

```
> df_ave[1,]
        ExtCal.Average ExtCal.Average.1 ExtCal.Average.2 ExtCal.Average.3 ExtCal.Average.4 ExtCal.Average.5
Isotope            7Li              11B              31P             63Cu             66Zn             85Rb
        ExtCal.Average.6 ExtCal.Average.7 ExtCal.Average.8 ExtCal.Average.9 ExtCal.Average.10 ExtCal.Average.11
Isotope             88Sr             90Zr            137Ba            139La             140Ce             141Pr
        ExtCal.Average.12 ExtCal.Average.13 ExtCal.Average.14 ExtCal.Average.15 ExtCal.Average.16
Isotope             146Nd             147Sm             153Eu             157Gd             172Yb
        ExtCal.Average.17 ExtCal.Average.18 ExtCal.Average.19 ExtCal.Average.20
Isotope             178Hf             208Pb             232Th              238U
```

I want to convert that row to characters (so I can then use it to replace the column names with it), but if I do `as.character(df_ave[1,])`, I get:

```
[1] "10" "6"  "5"  "10" "10" "10" "10" "10" "7"  "7"  "6"  "6"  "7"  "6"  "7"  "6"  "7"  "6"  "8"  "6"  "6"
```

Not what I expected!! What do I do wrong??

Same thing for the 2nd row, it's a factor with 11 levels that I want to convert to numeric (without 2 digits after the decimal point, not integer):

```
> df_ave[2,]
         ExtCal.Average   ExtCal.Average.1   ExtCal.Average.2  ExtCal.Average.3   ExtCal.Average.4
3622 406.69367683495113 125.40906252040027 93581.601747523237 3003.005804863546 19973.538736364932
       ExtCal.Average.5   ExtCal.Average.6 ExtCal.Average.7   ExtCal.Average.8   ExtCal.Average.9
3622 3.9733143041662951 103289.61846650975 89140.8626528866 104283.72610637423 13235.807622402481
      ExtCal.Average.10  ExtCal.Average.11  ExtCal.Average.12  ExtCal.Average.13  ExtCal.Average.14
3622 27535.452396889865 3566.5632181365959 14399.937899081722 3284.1060413886876 1069.0985077873447
     ExtCal.Average.15  ExtCal.Average.16  ExtCal.Average.17  ExtCal.Average.18 ExtCal.Average.19
3622 3555.409906877464 1657.8443498763834 2314.1788460028692 2057.1117900629424 3011.643780160347
      ExtCal.Average.20
3622 552.89402766758417
```

I tried: `> as.numeric(paste(df_ave[2,]))` but get:

```
[1]  7  7 10  7  6  7  4  9  5  6  7  7  6  7  5  7  6  7  7  7  9
```

Clearly not the expected level.
I get the same result if I enter `> as.numeric(df_ave[2,])`.
I guess it's returning the factor level, not the value itself??
Any help appreciated. These factors are driving me nuts.

Comment: Hey Tony, its really hard to read your code. Try to get all your rows on one line. If you then use the code sample button, stackoverflow will give us a scroll bar on the bottom to read right...

Comment: If you want to read your csv without converting automatically to factors, you can do `read.csv(...,stringsAsFactors=F)`.

Comment: thanks. Justin, how do I get all rows on one line? (would be useful to know for next time I post code). thanks

Comment: Why are you working with a row here? Typically variables are stored in columns and observations in rows. Is that not the case here?

Comment: it is, but I was trying to break it down to make easier for others... fail. (SO: reputation points? really? what is this, primary school?)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways, but the most straightforward I can find is to use as.matrix to first convert to character:

```
df <- data.frame(a=factor(1), b=factor(2), c=factor(3))
as.numeric(as.matrix(df)[1,])
```